# Menu item accel key works only after menu item has been shown

Tags: java, swt

I'm developing a SWT/JFace application using the libraries from Eclipse 3.4.1.
I encounter the following problem on Windows (Vista 32bit) and Ubuntu 8.10 32bit:

I create a menu bar in the createMenuManager method of the JFace ApplicationWindow. I add MenuManagers for file, edit and help.

I then add an ExitAction to the file MenuManager like so:

```
filemenu.add(new ExitAction(this));
```

The ExitAction is defined this way:

```
public class ExitAction extends Action {
  final ApplicationWindow window;

  public ExitAction(ApplicationWindow w) {

    this.window = w;
    setText("E&xit");
    setToolTipText("Exit the application");
    setAccelerator(SWT.MOD1 + 'Q');    
  }
}
```

Now when my application starts I want be able to press "CTRL+Q" to quit the application. This does however not work. Only AFTER I click on "File" in the menu bar and THEN clicking "CTRL+Q" the application will quit.

I've tried this with different accelerators- same behavior.

It does work however if I create a "MenuItem" instead of an "Action" to contribute to the menu bar.

Is this a SWT bug or do I miss something?

Torsten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: There is a duplicate bug of mine which also contains a workaround.
The bug url is: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=243758

Basically the workaround is to call `create()` on the `ApplicationWindow` and then `getMenuBarManager().updateAll(true);` which will force all menu items to get initialized.

Of course you have to call the above methods after you created the menu items.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `setAccelerator(.)` does nothing else than adding the appropriate text to your `MenuItem`. You are responsible to register for an `KeyUp` event and react on it.

You can use `Display.addFilter(SWT.KeyUp, myListener)` to register your `Listener` independently of your widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this is a bug in Eclipse 3.4.
I have submitted a bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=253078